# Contar valores iguais em um data frame e armazenar em outro no R

Tags: r

Preciso contar os valores iguais de uma coluna em um data frame (banco com o nome total_amostral) e armazenar o total em uma coluna de outro data frame (banco com o nome unicos) que contém os valores únicos do primeiro data frame. Logo os dois bancos são de tamanhos diferentes, o primeiro é maior que o segundo. Para isso utilizei o código abaixo, porém o R apresenta o erro de que o tamanho dos data frames são diferentes.

```
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
espaco_amostral<-data.frame(t(combn(y,m=4))) #Banco com a combinação do vetor y.
total_amostral<-data.frame(TOTAL=apply(espaco_amostral,1,sum)) #Banco com o somatórios das linhas do espaco_amostral.

unicos<-data.frame(unique(total_amostral)) #banco com valores únicos de total_amostral
contador<-0
for(i in unicos){
   for(e in total_amostral){
      ifelse(total_amostral[e,] == unicos[i,],
             unicos[,2]<-contador+1,unicos[,2]<-0)
   }
}
unicos
```

A credito que em `total_amostral[e,] == unicos[i,]` ele esteja comparando os bancos por inteiro. Como posso fazer para ele comparar cada elemento do banco `total_amostral` com o `unicos` e depois contar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu não tentaria reinventar a roda e usaria uma função pronta no `R` pra fazer isso.

```
library(dplyr)

total_amostral %>%
  group_by(TOTAL) %>%
  count()
# A tibble: 17 x 2
# Groups:   TOTAL [17]
   TOTAL     n
   <dbl> <int>
 1    10     1
 2    11     1
 3    12     2
 4    13     3
 5    14     5
 6    15     5
 7    16     7
 8    17     7
 9    18     8
10    19     7
11    20     7
12    21     5
13    22     5
14    23     3
15    24     2
16    25     1
17    26     1
```

O que eu fiz foi utilizar o pacote `dplyr` para agrupar e somar os teus dados:

- `%>%` é o operador pipe. Basicamente, ele pega o resultado que está à sua esquerda e lança para processamento no comando que está à sua direita. Por exemplo, ao fazer `total_amostral %>% group_by(TOTAL)`, eu estou pegando o data frame `total_amostral` sem processamento algum e agrupando seus valores de acordo com a coluna `TOTAL`
- `group_by` é uma função de agrupamento. Ela vai juntar o que for igual de acordo com algum critério. Neste caso, estou juntando os valores de `TOTAL` que sejam iguais
- por fim, `count()` vai simplesmente contar as ocorrências de cada elemento dentro dos grupos criados acima

Sendo iniciante no `R`, eu te sugiro procurar informações sobre o pacote `dplyr`. Ele vai te dar uma ajuda imensa na hora de pré-processar dados para análise ou fazer estatísticas descritivas básicas.

Answer (score 5):

A própria função `count()` pode aceitar o nome de uma coluna como argumento e ela então conta os valores únicos daquela coluna. Desta forma é possível simplificar a solução oferecida pelo @MarcusNunes.

```
library(dplyr)
unicos %>% 
  count(TOTAL)
# A tibble: 17 x 2
   TOTAL     n
   <dbl> <int>
 1    10     1
 2    11     1
 3    12     1
 4    13     1
 5    14     1
 6    15     1
 7    16     1
 8    17     1
 9    18     1
10    19     1
11    20     1
12    21     1
13    22     1
14    23     1
15    24     1
16    25     1
17    26     1
```

Adicionar o argumento`sort = TRUE` no chamado de  `count()` organiza o `data.frame` resultado do maior `n` para o menor.

Answer (score 4):

Eis duas formas só com R base.

```
as.data.frame(table(total_amostral$TOTAL))
#   Var1 Freq
#1    10    1
#2    11    1
#3    12    2
#4    13    3
#5    14    5
#6    15    5
#7    16    7
#8    17    7
#9    18    8
#10   19    7
#11   20    7
#12   21    5
#13   22    5
#14   23    3
#15   24    2
#16   25    1
#17   26    1

aggregate(TOTAL ~ factor(TOTAL), total_amostral, length)
#   factor(TOTAL) TOTAL
#1             10     1
#2             11     1
#3             12     2
#4             13     3
#5             14     5
#6             15     5
#7             16     7
#8             17     7
#9             18     8
#10            19     7
#11            20     7
#12            21     5
#13            22     5
#14            23     3
#15            24     2
#16            25     1
#17            26     1
```

Depois podem-se mudar os nomes das colunas destes dois resultados.

```
res1 <- as.data.frame(table(total_amostral$TOTAL))
names(res1)[1] <- "TOTAL"

res2 <- aggregate(TOTAL ~ factor(TOTAL), total_amostral, length)
names(res2) <- c("TOTAL", "Freq")
```

Answer (score 4):

Também é possível fazer isso em uma linha com o pacote `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(total_amostral) # transforme total_amostral em data.table

total_amostral[, .N, by = "TOTAL"]
```

Resultado:

```
> total_amostral[, .N, by = "TOTAL"]
    TOTAL N
 1:    10 1
 2:    11 1
 3:    12 2
 4:    13 3
 5:    14 5
 6:    15 5
 7:    16 7
 8:    17 7
 9:    18 8
10:    19 7
11:    20 7
12:    21 5
13:    22 5
14:    23 3
15:    24 2
16:    25 1
17:    26 1
```

Se os dados são grandes, `data.table` será provavelmente a melhor opção. Usando `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` para medir o tempo para fazer a operação:

```
y <- c(1:40) # aumentei a amostra deliberadamente
espaco_amostral<-data.frame(t(combn(y,m=4))) #Banco com a combinação do vetor y.
total_amostral<-data.frame(TOTAL=apply(espaco_amostral,1,sum)) #Banco com o somatórios das linhas do espaco_amostral.

unicos<-data.frame(unique(total_amostral)) #banco com valores únicos de total_amostral

library(data.table)
setDT(total_amostral)
total_amostral[, .N, by = "TOTAL"]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  data.table = total_amostral[, .N, by = "TOTAL"], 
  dplyr = count(total_amostral, TOTAL), 
  base_1 = as.data.frame(table(total_amostral$TOTAL)),
  base_2 = aggregate(TOTAL ~ factor(TOTAL), total_amostral, length), 
  times = 100
)

Unit: milliseconds
       expr        min         lq       mean     median
 data.table   1.996741   2.501213   3.205596   3.083716
      dplyr   6.948481   8.809759  10.996959  10.733755
     base_1   8.100727  10.199018  12.744832  12.457566
     base_2 126.146868 157.310745 202.200196 199.385773
         uq        max neval cld
   3.771053   8.371286   100  a 
  12.777168  29.598866   100  a 
  14.908276  21.049273   100  a 
 236.910523 403.407512   100   b
```

Comment: `data.table` nunca decepciona quando se trata de performance

Comment: Sim, é bastante rápido. Aqui está um comparativo com outras alternativas (incluindo python e spark): [https://twitter.com/MattDowle/status/1074746218645938176](https://twitter.com/MattDowle/status/1074746218645938176)